# What are all the options for the "edge" part of the TikZ \path command?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, paths

I am drawing edges in a graph using a command like

```
\path (nodeName1) edge [->] (nodeName2)
```

The only way I have learned what options can go into the square brackets after "edge" is by looking at examples.  Where can I find everything that can possibly be used as an option here?

Comment: Where else if not in the [pgf/tikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) manual?

Comment: @T.D: Sometimes easier said than found...

Comment: In v2.10 most of the interesting options are listed in section 15 *Actions on Paths*. Also useful are `bend left`/`right` (p470).

Comment: @Caramdir Exactly. I knew about `bend left` and `bend right` but was looking for a way to be more specific without having to specify exactly how the edge should look.  I found my solution in the options `in`, `out`, and `looseness`. Even though Jake's answer was helpful, if you make your comment into an answer, I will accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 10):

Saying

```
\path (nodeName1) edge [->] (nodeName2);
```

is the same as saying

```
\path (nodeName1);
\path [every edge, ->] (nodeName1) -- (nodeName2);
```

`every edge` is a style that by defaults just contains `draw`. This means that you can pass any option to the `edge` operation that you could also pass to a `\path [draw]` operation (e.g. colours, line thicknesses, decorations, etc.).